# django how to secure my project

Tags: django, security, encryption, hash, https

I work on a project where I'll have to configure remotely some products. 
These products have a sim card and can connect on internet through gsm so I won't be able to connect to them directly.

Customers will connect on my website to make configuration requests on their products by filling forms, when they are done, I save in DB all products new config and I will send a sms to each products, the sms make the products know that they have to connect with http to an url specified in the sms, when they connect to the url I identify the product with their serial number and send their new configurations.

Now I don't really know how to secure all the data sended in the sms or the manage the authentification from the product to my server.

I thought to make an authentification based on a MD5/SHA HASH formula, but the problem is that the secret used to hash will be stored in the product and if the secret and the formula gets to be known, it will become critical.
Maybe using dynamic hash with date of the day with product infos would be better. HTTPS could resolve everything maybe but I just can't only use the serial number of the product as authorisation.

I thought also to add a private key infra but I think its too complex.
I would encrypt data with product public key for example and the product would encrypt data with my server public key, but I don't know if its too hard to implement this architecture.

I use django framework, ngnix.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: To narrow I would like to know if using an hash to authentify my product connections could be safe if the hash formula contains no passwords hardcoded in the product and in my code, all formula data would contain product serial number, date of the day maybe other product info.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusing what a 'hash' is, with encrypting/decrypting data.  A hash is typically one way, with no means to (easily) 'unhash' the information that has been transferred.

The weakest link in your design is the very limited SMS (text messaging) system for transferring the data.  It lacks the ability to use a large/full character set (such as binary) - which means encrypted messages would have to be quite long to be secure.  But it also limits the length of messages, so these long encrypted messages could not be sent.

As mentioned in the comments, this question is too general to provide a specific answer to.  But if these were 'smart' devices, a dedicated configuration 'app' - using SSL - would likely be your best solution.